# JBPM issue with Maria DB Galera were Primary key mandatory

Tags: mariadb, jbpm, kie-server

JBPM issue with Maria DB Galera were Primary key mandatory.
Some tables in JBPM db schema have no primary key.

- If I add a primary key column along with them what will be the impact?
- Is there nay other way I can get ride of this problem?

Currently we have Mariadb as the only database option to use.

```
create table EventTypes (
    InstanceId bigint not null,
    element varchar(255)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
create table PeopleAssignments_PotOwners (
        task_id bigint not null,
        entity_id varchar(255) not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Source for MariaDB primary Key mandatory:
[mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/)

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PeopleAssignments_PotOwners` looks like a many:many mapping table between tasks and entities??  If so, then the 'natural' `PRIMARY KEY` would be

```
PRIMARY KEY(task_id, entity_id)
```

(in either order).

Perhaps ditto for the other table?

More discussion of efficiency in many:many tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

If you don't have a 'natural' primary key composed of one (or more) columns, add

```
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```